# Find mongodb documents where linked document property equals value

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDb document which links to another in a different Collection.

Collection A is like

`{ _id: ..., contact_id: ObjectId('1234') }`

Contacts collection something like:

`{ _id: ObjectId('1234'), name: 'Joe' }`

I'm trying to find all A documents where the linked contact's name is 'Joe'

I can't get my head around how you would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a single query because MongoDB doesn't support joins.  Instead, you have to break it into two queries: the first to get the `_id` of Joe, and the second to get his `A` docs.  I'm not sure what language you're using, but in the shell:

```js
db.A.find({contact_id: db.contacts.findOne({name: 'Joe'})._id});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using [aggregation lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html), introduced in MongoDB v3.2, after @johnnyhk answer.

```js
db.A.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        localField: "contact_id",
        from: "Contacts",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "contact"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "contact.name": "Joe"
      }
    }
  ]
)
```